# Two Ajax calls not working concurrently (heroku)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, heroku, concurrency

I have this following code:

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    $('#content1').load('database.php');
    setInterval (function() 
    { 
        $.post('status.php', { id: '1'}, function(responseText, responseStatus)
        { 
            $('#content2').html(responseText); 
        });  
    }, 5000);
});
```

Basically, I am calling the database.php to do some database insertions, and using a periodic interval to get the status of its progress. The problem is that during the insertions, the interval posts are giving me request timeout error. Only once the database.php has finished processing, text in the content2 is written.

For now I am using very simple code in status.php file, just to see if I can get a response while the database.php is being processed. Here is the code (very simple):

```
<?php
    echo "hello";
?>
```

I dont know why I am getting a timeout error and not getting an response. As you can see, in the statuse.php file, I am not using any php session variables which can block the calls. The funny thing is that once the processing of the database is complete, I do get a response. That is, I get the text 'hello'.

Comment: What is giving you the timout error?
This has nothing to do with beeing synchronious, if the calls where synchronious, one after another would be called and while not finished, everything else would be blocked.

Comment: Can you explain what you think asynchronous means?

Comment: For every interval call of the status.php, I get a timeout error during the computation.

Comment: Why would the fact that AJAX is asynchronous lead you to believe that your calls should not timeout?

Comment: hmm can you recommend me a better title please

Comment: I still don`t understand what is giving you the error. Is this a PHP or a Javascript error? Do you see it in firebug? Can you post it?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes Code H12

Comment: Nothing in your post says that you`re on Heroku. The timeout you having seems not to be Javascript or AJAX related in any way.

Comment: hmm ok thanks @Nic, Ill try an look into it then

Comment: I think I've just realised what's happening. Is it that you're asking the browser "load this, this and this" and what it's doing is going "whoa hang on, I'll wait for the first one to finish before loading the next"?

Comment: I changed $('#content1').load('database.php'); to $.post('database.php'); Still same problem =/. I appreciate the suggestion though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my service was only using one dyno. Since the database processing takes some time and is handled by my single dyno, the other AJAX request couldn't be handled. To allow concurrency, more dynos are required.

This however, is not encouraged as one would be needing a dyno for each user currently using the service, plus an another dyno to handle the simple AJAX requests. It is encouraged to use workers (for example IronWorker that Heroku supports) so that these long processes would not result in having your dynos busy to the extent of not handling other requests.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using sessions. PHP's default file-based session handler **LOCKS** the session while a script is active, so from the moment `session_start()` is called, no other script using the same session can be run in parallel, as those other scripts will block and hang on the session_start() call until the first script finishes.

If you want your "progress" check calls to succeed, you'll have to do a `session_write_close()` in the database script so that the session lock is relinquished and other requests on that session can proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your post. So even if status.php doesnt start a session or makes use of any session variables, database.php will still lock and wont allow any other calls to be processed?

Comment: if there's no sessions, then something else is happening. maybe your browser has a limit of one "in flight" ajax request, so the status requests must wait until the database request completes.

Comment: this is what I think is happening Marc

Comment: @MarcB yea most probably ur right. It could also be due to the fact that I am using a free heroku account, and may only allow one ajax request. However, from all the content I looked at, I didnt find this stated.